# MySQL: Selecting data based on values from multiple rows

Tags: mysql

I am trying to write a SQL statement that selects data out of a table where an individual has multiple values in the same column.  For example, based on the table below: I need a query to select all of the rows for all of the individuals who have both a bat and a baseball in the “Toy” column.

```
------------------------
| ID | Name | Toy      |
------------------------
|  1 | Jack | Bat      |
|  2 | Jim  | Baseball |
|  3 | Jack | Baseball |
|  4 | John | Bat      |
|  5 | Jim  | Football |
|  6 | Jack | Glove    |
------------------------
```

I would like the results to be something like:

```
-------------------
| Name | Toy      |
-------------------
| Jack | Bat      |
| Jack | Baseball |
-------------------
```

I hope this makes sense.  Thanks.

Comment: You're going to need to clarify this. I thought you wanted a query that selects ALL names that have more than one toy. Juergen, and others, apparently, think you want one where there is a specific combination of two toys.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select distinct t.name, t.toy
from your_table t
where name in 
(
  select name
  from your_table
  where toy in ('bat','baseball') 
  group by name
  having count(distinct toy) = 2
)
and toy in ('bat','baseball')
```

If you just need the name you can do

```
  select name
  from your_table
  where toy in ('bat','baseball') 
  group by name
  having count(distinct toy) = 2
```

### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a513cd/3)

Comment: No, I want `=2` because it is exactly 2. Always, because of the `where` condition.